# Как запустить сервис вне UI потока?

Tags: android, service

Собственно у меня есть сервис, который запускается в активности, и продолжает работу после ее уничтожения. Во время уничтожения активности сервис перезапускается. Если я правильно понял чтобы запустить `Service` сразу вне потока *UI* необходимо в манифесте объявить `android:process="my.own.ProcessName"`, но это не работает. Что я не так делаю? Или, может, использовать `IntentService` т.к. он сразу стартует в новом потоке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто запустите `IntentService` - это специальная версия `Service`, который работает в своем потоке (не в UI) и никому не мешает.

Comment: Подскажите какую функцию выполнятет 'android:process'? из дока 'But component can override the default with its own process attribute, allowing you to spread your application across multiple processes.' я так понимаю что это обязует сервис запустится в новом потоке?

Comment: Читайте [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/137/service/4563/defining-the-process-of-a-service#t=20160721193509600605)

Comment: Гуру), растолкуй, плз... я так понял, что в данном случае service запускается в номов потоке  чтобы не вешать UI но в том же процессе. При закрытии активности поток уничтожается вместе с процессом.

Comment: А вообще как оказалось в моем случае лучше всего подходит startForeground )

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
public void run(){
getApplicationContext().bindService(
        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAndroidUpnpServiceImpl.class),
        serviceConnection,
        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
    );
}
};
t.start();
```

Comment: Подскажите какую функцию выполнятет 'android:process'?